# How to fix an error of website iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, iframe

When I go to this url : (warning: *some Ad-blocker is recommended*)

https://openload.co/embed/M4pSomdJWME/?c1_file=http://tugaflix.com/legendas/716bac991518958ad95df18200c906c3.srt&c1_label=Legenda

The web-page link loads fine, without errors.

However, when I try to load same page via `iframe` in my html code, an error appears:

My html code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="600" height="700" 
        src="https://openload.co/embed/M4pSomdJWME/?c1_file=http://tugaflix.com/legendas/716bac991518958ad95df18200c906c3.srt&c1_label=Legenda">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below image: Error result within my iframe. How to fix such error?

[image]

Comment: Ooh, popups. Those make a nice addition to my ad blocker. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to design/code your own player interface then one loading option is to use a `<video>` tag instead of via `<iframe>` tag...

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls crossorigin="anonymous">
<source src="https://oload.stream/stream/M4pSomdJWME~1508775093~213.205.0.0~IzmpIUe0?mime=true" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I'm not going to tell you how to <s>steal</s> access any video by code, but some advice is:

1) You can see in the source code that a server `1508775191~213.205.0.0` is accessed for media files including subtitle VTT file). Study rest of source code. Consider why `token` is mentioned and why `referrer` is checked. What can you do pass and get same access?

2) By using your browser's Developer Tools (especially "network" and "console" tabs), you can find the related `https://oload.stream/stream/` url for any future updates or alternate embeds.

PS:

> *"but, this [tugaflix.com/Episodio?E=2310910&S2](http://tugaflix.com/Episodio?E=2310910&S2) website is using that iframe"*

Look at source code of: http://tugaflix.com/Episodio?E=2310910&S2/ 
You will see that no `iframe` is mentioned or used... They are even using two different player interfaces so you cannot assume that **tugaflix.com** is loading this page `https://oload.stream/embed/M4pSomdJWME` within some `iframe`. They are instead accessing the MP4 video file from some server called`https://lemonade-fruit.fruithosted.net/`

Answer (score 1):

The target site has code that prevents it from being shown in an Iframe. Unfortunately you will not be able to use that url in an Iframe.

Comment: They probably allow certain domains to iframe them, but not all domains.

Comment: @rajdevkumar i can't see any iframes in given site ?

Comment: @FastSnail , you must click in ver vídeo