# How to extract an embedded video from an URL?

Tags: java, android, url, video, embedded-resource

I wanted to ask if there is a java code to directly extract a embedded video from a streaming site.

With some research I managed to find this solution: [How to get direct link of remote video from embedded url within a url in Android using JSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858581/how-to-get-direct-link-of-remote-video-from-embedded-url-within-a-url-in-android)

but in this solution there are errors in code, for example:

```
String url = "https://www.wunderground.com/webcams/cadot1/902/video.html";
int timeout = 100 * 1000;
// Extract video URL
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(timeout).get();
Element script = doc.getElementById("inner-content")
    .getElementsByTag("script").last();
String content = script.data();
int indexOfUrl = content.indexOf("url");
int indexOfComma = content.indexOf(',', indexOfUrl);
String videoUrl = "https:" + content.substring(indexOfUrl + 6, indexOfComma 
- 1);
System.out.println(videoUrl);
```

I cant get last element:

```
    .getElementsByTag("script").last();
```

There is a tutorial or something that explain how to get embedded video url?

For expample this is the urlvideo: https://openload.co/embed/MB6RMqNrvp0/Episodio_017.mkv.mp4

and this is the embeddedvideourl: https://1fiag5y.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/9pL6teltc-w0jPxJ/MB6RMqNrvp0/Episodio_017.mkv.mp4?mime=true   //I need this

Tnks.

Comment: Is this even legal?

Comment: It's only for study

Comment: Noone know how to do?

Comment: @francescobocci look at: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873989/how-to-fix-an-error-of-website-iframe** ... PS: As for that `wunderground.com/webcams/` all you have to do is use Java's `String` functions to extract the text of MP4 video file. It's right there in the HTML source code: **http://icons.wunderground.com/webcamcurrent/c/a/cadot1/902/current.mp4?e=1508694576**

Comment: Thanks for answer but, I know how to find embedded link (is vary easy). My problem is: "Is possible create script in android-java to take this url?

Comment: But no one tell me if is possible find url with android

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to compare the DOM model that you have in browser developer tools and one retrieved by JSoup and they don't match.

Please note that developer tools will show you DOM as it is at the moment of inspection after all DHTML modifications applied by page JavaScript. JSoup loads page contents as they are loaded initially (equivalent to *view page source* in browser) and is not capable for JavaScript evaluation. So these two DOM models can be significantly different.

You should verify how to get your data against initial page state.

Comment: I know how to manually find embedded url using chrome, but I need a java code to do this